# Monaco Editor get source code index of caret

Tags: monaco-editor

Is there a way to get the caret position as index in the source code string?
I know I can get the position, which will give me an object, containing the line and column, but is there a way to either get or convert line + column to string char index?

For example if I have:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
```

and I place the caret to be just before ".Data", I know how to get the line + col coordinate (line 1, col 13), but how to get the char array index (should be something like 25)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following sample code in the [Monaco Playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html) to try things out.

The function you are looking for is [ITextModel](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.itextmodel.html)'s [getOffsetAt(IPosition)](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.itextmodel.html#getoffsetat) function.

```js
var model = monaco.editor.createModel(
    "using System;\n" +
    "using System.Data;",
    "csharp"
); 

var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    model
});

var offset = model.getOffsetAt({ lineNumber: 2, column: 13 });
alert(offset);
```

Answer (score 4):

Okay, not sure if this is the best way, but the following seems to work properly:

1. Get the editor position (line + column).
2. Get the text until that position.
3. Get the length of that text

Here is an example code:

```
var line = window.editor.getPosition().lineNumber;
var col = window.editor.getPosition().column;
var textUntilPosition = window.editor.model.getValueInRange({ startLineNumber: 1, startColumn: 1, endLineNumber: line, endColumn: col });
var currentPos = textUntilPosition.length;
```